# SftpInboundGateway does not refetch remote file as long as local copy exists?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I have a `SftpInboundAdapter` configured and working.
After some tests I realized that the remote file is not refeched a second time as long as the local pendant exists, i.e. there is no attempt made at all to reconnect to the SFTP server. Even if the remote file's content has changed. Even if the local file was renamed.
Under that condition I figured, what goal might be to change the filename on the way to its local place by means of `.setLocalFilenameExpression(...)` other than a cosmetic filename correction? Particularly when it has to be deleted soon to be ready for the next remote file with an indentical name to come?

**Question 1**: Is my observation correct?

Then I thought about that scenario: Every month a new file, with the same name but of course having different data, is to come to the SFTP server from an external source. My `SftpInboundAdapter` should fetch that file, process its content and leave a local copy for later review. Its filename should consequently bare a timestamp of the date of reception. And it should of course not have any impact on the receiving process of  the new file a month later (as I indicated above).

**Question 2**: How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually it is a problem of your test suite. You must start from a clean local directory each time you run the test. Just because there is a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` for `localFilter` by default: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound. Therefore existing file is not considered the second time the poll request happens. Just because such a file has been filtered out in the previous cycle. Since your test does refresh the memory, all the filtered files have gone, but local copy is still the in the directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Artem! But would you mind to explain what will change at a productive-like environment? There also will be a clean local directory just before the first transfer. Do I have to clean it after every reception? How do I do the scenario with the backup copies of the received files baring the time stamp of reception?

Comment: You can do that with a separate inbound channel adapter for `FileReadingMessageSource`for that local dir. To avoid duplications you should consider to use a persistent `MetadataStore` for that local filter option: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound, https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/meta-data-store.html#metadata-store. This way all the filtered already files are not going to be treated again

Comment: Even if I copy the received file in the local directory to a backup file, SI memorize this and has the copy as "original filename" the second time. I think I need a setting which let the filter forget anything from last time. Is this possible? How would I make this?

Comment: See `ResettableFileListFilter`, like I mentioned that `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`. So, you can call its `remove(File)` and you will be able to pull that file again since it won't be present in the store to filter out.

Comment: Thanks Artem! But I still have difficulties to find something about `ResettableFileListFilter`. Can you please give me the exact link?

Comment: M-m-m. No straightforward explanation over there, but here is something: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#recovering-from-failures. You can use `SimpleMetadataStore` backed by some external `Map`. And whenever you need, you can `clear()` that map.

Comment: You mean something in the way of `.localFilter(new FileSystemPersistentFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(metadata)))` at my `.from(Sft.inboundAdapter(...)` flow? With `private ConcurrentMap<String,String> metadata = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();` in the same config file?
Having that I can use `metadata.clear()` to remove the filter's memory?
How exactly go `FileSystemPersistentFileListFilter,SimpleMetadataStore` together? The DSL example just not comes with that feature...

Comment: Even with `SimpleMetadataStore`, which is reset with each application restart, if the local file exists - even copied/moved under a new name - the adapter does not reconnect to SFTP to get the new file. Maybe the constant filename with each reception from SFTP is a problem? Maybe the constant file creation date is a problem?

Comment: Well, if you restart application and clean up local dir in between, then you don't need all of that "reset" massage. All the metadata are just in the memory. And of course, it is cleaned on each restart. See `preserveTimestamp` option to make local files unique not only by their name.

Comment: But then I don't understand why a new file (with the same name) is not read by `com.jcraft.jsch` a second time as long as a local copy exists, even after copying and renaming it. Should I move the copy to another local folder (other than the folder used with `.localDirectory(...)`) to hide it from the filters?

Comment: Well, yes, local files even after renaming must not pass the filter otherwise they are picked up on the next restart. So, better to have local dir empty.

Comment: I did as you suggested, Artem, but it does not work as required: I ask again more precisely with code snippets: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69511643/how-do-i-force-the-sftpinboundadapter-to-connect-and-get-a-file-every-time-a-tas>.

Comment: Ok. I’ll look on Monday