# How do I force the SftpInboundAdapter to connect and get a file every time a task is executed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

This is my scenario: I get every month a file to `my.sftp.server.de` with event data as JSON. The file has always exactly the same name. I know when the file is provided.

The file then shall be fetched, processed, removed and backuped with another filename showing the timestamp of procession. This is done with a subscribed MessageHandler `deleteLocalFileService`.

Here are my Spring Integration classes:

```
@Autowired
private Executor taskExecutor;

private ConcurrentMap<String, String> metadata = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@Bean
public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory(TransferChannel transferChannel) {
    LOG.debug("sftpSessionFactory");
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    ...
    return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(sf);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundFlow(TransferContext context) {
    LOG.debug("sftpInboundFlow");
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(sftpSessionFactory(context.getChannel()))
                .preserveTimestamp(context.isPreserveTimestamp())
                .remoteDirectory(context.getRemoteDir())
                .regexFilter(context.getRemoteFilename())
                .deleteRemoteFiles(context.isRemoteRemove())
                .autoCreateLocalDirectory(context.isAutoCreateLocalDir())
                .localFilenameExpression(context.getLocalFilename())
                .localDirectory(new File(context.getLocalDir()))
                .localFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(
                        new SimpleMetadataStore(metadata), "")),
            e -> e.id("sftpInboundAdapter")
                .autoStartup(false)
                .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(15000).taskExecutor(taskExecutor))
            )
        .transform(Transformers.fromJson(Event[].class))
        .channel("sftpInputChannel")
        .get();
}

@Bean
public PublishSubscribeChannel sftpInputChannel() {
    LOG.debug("sftpInputChannel");
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpInputChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    LOG.debug("MessageHandler-handler");
    return new MessageHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            LOG.debug("handleMessage message={}", message);
        }
    };
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpInputChannel")
public MessageHandler deleteLocalFileService() {
    LOG.debug("MessageHandler-deleteLocalFileService");
    return new MessageHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            File f1 = (File) message.getHeaders().get("file_originalFile");
            try {
                // create backup copy in another directory
                // (otherwise the remote and local filters avoid fetch of the (new) file again)
                File f2 = new File("/home/app/sftp-inbound-work/EventData.txt.SAVE." +
                        LocalDateTime.now().format(ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
                FileUtil.copyFile(f1, f2);
                LOG.debug("deleteLocalFileService backup={} created", f2);

                // remove received file
                if (!f1.delete()) {
                    throw new MessagingException("Could not remove local file, " + f1.getName());
                };
                metadata.clear();
                LOG.debug("deleteLocalFileService file={} removed", f1);
            }
            catch (IOException io) {
                LOG.error("Exception copying local file {}", io);
                throw new MessagingException("Could not backup local file, " + f1.getName());
            }
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel controlChannel() {
    LOG.debug("controlChannel");
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "controlChannel")
public ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean controlBus() {
    LOG.debug("controlBus");
    ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean expressionControlBusFactoryBean = new ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean();
    return expressionControlBusFactoryBean;
}
```

Because I know when the event data file is provided from a external source, I have a method `runAsTask` which is executed as Spring Scheduler Task. The method adds a ChannelInterceptor to get the content of the file, then starts the Spring Integration ensemble via a ControlChannel message and finally get and return the event data from the received file.

Here is the task method with its heart: the `getFile()` method:

```
private static final int FILE_GET_TIMEOUT_SEC = 30;

@Autowired
AbstractMessageChannel sftpInputChannel;

@Autowired
MessageChannel controlChannel;

@Scheduled(cron = "${com.harry.potter.job.tasks.harry-potter-events-task.frequency}")
public void runAsTask() {

    if (env.isEnabled()) {
        LOG.info("runAsTask: Storing Event Data, frequency={}", env.getFrequency());
        jobLOG.info("---------------------------------------------------------------");
        jobLOG.info("Job started: Storing Event Data");
    } else {
        LOG.debug("runAsTask");
        LOG.debug("runAsTask {} not enabled: Storing Event Data, aborted.", jobId);
        return;
    }

    try {
        events = getFile();

        /* processing of the event data */
        
        jobLOG.info("Okay, send okay mail");
        sendOkayMail();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("{} failed! Exception: {}", jobId, e);
        jobLOG.info("Job has errors, send error mail");
        sendErrorMail();
    } finally {
        LOG.info("{} finished", jobId);
        jobLOG.info("Job finished");
    }
}

public List<Event> getFile() {
    LOG.debug("getFile");

    final List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    sftpInputChannel.addInterceptor(new ChannelInterceptor() {
        // capture the message and count down the latch
        @Override
        public void postSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, boolean sent) {
            LOG.debug("postSend channel={}, sent={}", channel.toString(), sent);
            LOG.trace("postSend message={}", message.getPayload());

            // read and transform the content
            Arrays.stream((Event[]) message.getPayload()).forEach(e -> events.add(e));

            // signal: work has done
            latch.countDown();
            ChannelInterceptor.super.postSend(message, channel, sent);
        }
        
    });

    boolean sent = controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@sftpInboundAdapter.start()"));
    LOG.debug("getFile 'Start' control message sent successfully={}", sent);

    try {
        LOG.debug("getFile, waiting for the file to be received, timeout={}s", FILE_GET_TIMEOUT_SEC);
        if (latch.await(FILE_GET_TIMEOUT_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            return events;
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOG.warn("getFile, job was interrupted");
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException("expected file not available");
}
```

**There are two problems**:

1. The `ChannelInterceptor` is added multiple times (see in the LOG `postSend channel=bean 'sftpInputChannel' ...`). Where should I add the interceptor to just have one? Or how can I check if an interceptor already was added?
2. The file is fetched from SFTP just the first time (see the `com.jcraft.jsch` lines in the LOG). All subsequent task cycles no more negociation with the SFTP host occured. To fetch the file every cycle I was told to use a `SimpleMetadataStore` for the `LocalDirectoryFilter` backed by a Map and clear this map after processing the file, which I do. What do I have to change to have the file fetched from SFTP each time the task is running?

Here is the LOG having started the task for two times:

```
2021-10-09 01:35:52.688  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.h.potter.job.MyJobApplication          : The following profiles are active: test,cdsclient
2021-10-09 01:35:53.960  WARN [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2021-10-09 01:35:54.141  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=301a6a9f-3809-32e6-b15b-e640dd198297
2021-10-09 01:35:54.149  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2021-10-09 01:35:54.155  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2021-10-09 01:35:54.160  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2021-10-09 01:35:54.282  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-10-09 01:35:54.300  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationChannelResolver' of type [org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-10-09 01:35:54.301  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-10-09 01:35:54.363  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1668 ms
2021-10-09 01:35:54.967  WARN [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2021-10-09 01:35:54.967  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2021-10-09 01:35:54.981  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@db52778f
2021-10-09 01:35:55.158 DEBUG [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.l.c.c.c.sftpConfiguration              : sftpInputChannel
2021-10-09 01:35:55.224 DEBUG [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.l.c.c.c.sftpConfiguration              : controlChannel
2021-10-09 01:35:55.476 DEBUG [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.l.c.c.c.sftpConfiguration              : transferChannel
2021-10-09 01:35:55.477 DEBUG [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.l.c.c.c.sftpConfiguration              : transferContext
2021-10-09 01:35:55.477 DEBUG [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.l.c.c.c.sftpConfiguration              : sftpSessionFactory
2021-10-09 01:35:55.486 DEBUG [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.l.c.c.c.sftpConfiguration              : sftpInboundFlow
2021-10-09 01:35:55.587 DEBUG [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.l.c.c.c.sftpConfiguration              : MessageHandler-handler
2021-10-09 01:35:55.588 DEBUG [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.l.c.c.c.sftpConfiguration              : MessageHandler-deleteLocalFileService
2021-10-09 01:35:55.589 DEBUG [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.l.c.c.c.sftpConfiguration              : controlBus
2021-10-09 01:35:56.271  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2021-10-09 01:35:56.335  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2021-10-09 01:35:56.335  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application-1.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2021-10-09 01:35:56.335  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2021-10-09 01:35:56.335  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {json-to-object-transformer} as a subscriber to the 'sftpInboundFlow.channel#0' channel
2021-10-09 01:35:56.335  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application-1.sftpInboundFlow.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2021-10-09 01:35:56.335  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean 'sftpInboundFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/harry/potter/job/config/sftpConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method sftpInboundFlow'
2021-10-09 01:35:56.335  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {message-handler:sftpConfiguration.handler.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'sftpInputChannel' channel
2021-10-09 01:35:56.335  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application-1.sftpInputChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2021-10-09 01:35:56.335  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean 'sftpConfiguration.handler.serviceActivator'
2021-10-09 01:35:56.335  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {message-handler:sftpConfiguration.deleteLocalFileService.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'sftpInputChannel' channel
2021-10-09 01:35:56.335  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application-1.sftpInputChannel' has 2 subscriber(s).
2021-10-09 01:35:56.336  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean 'sftpConfiguration.deleteLocalFileService.serviceActivator'
2021-10-09 01:35:56.336  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {service-activator:sftpConfiguration.controlBus.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'controlChannel' channel
2021-10-09 01:35:56.336  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application-1.controlChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2021-10-09 01:35:56.336  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean 'sftpConfiguration.controlBus.serviceActivator'
2021-10-09 01:35:56.344  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2021-10-09 01:35:56.380  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2021-10-09 01:35:56.449  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2021-10-09 01:35:56.449  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2021-10-09 01:35:56.550  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2021-10-09 01:35:56.550  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2021-10-09 01:35:56.722  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2021-10-09 01:35:56.743  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2021-10-09 01:35:56.743  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2021-10-09 01:35:56.743  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2021-10-09 01:35:56.743  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2021-10-09 01:35:56.743  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2021-10-09 01:35:56.743  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2021-10-09 01:35:56.743  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2021-10-09 01:35:56.953  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
2021-10-09 01:35:56.955  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Not registering with Eureka server per configuration
2021-10-09 01:35:56.958  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1633736156957 with initial instances count: 69
2021-10-09 01:35:56.959  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application MyJob with eureka with status UP
2021-10-09 01:35:56.986  INFO [] --- [http-nio-8080-exec-220]  c.h.potter.job.MyJobApplication          : Started MyJobApplication in 5.36 seconds (JVM running for 996008.867)
2021-10-09 01:36:00.000  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : runAsTask: Storing Event Data, frequency=0/30 * * * * *
2021-10-09 01:36:00.001  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  job-MyJob                                : ---------------------------------------------------------------
2021-10-09 01:36:00.001  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  job-MyJob                                : Job started: Storing Event Data
2021-10-09 01:36:00.001 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : getFile
2021-10-09 01:36:00.031  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : started bean 'sftpInboundAdapter'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/harry/potter/job/config/sftpConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method sftpInboundFlow'
2021-10-09 01:36:00.033 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : getFile 'Start' control message sent successfully=true
2021-10-09 01:36:00.033 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : getFile, waiting for the file to be received, timeout=60s
2021-10-09 01:36:00.055  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-2]  com.jcraft.jsch                          : Connecting to my.sftp.server.de     port 22
2021-10-09 01:36:00.057  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-2]  com.jcraft.jsch                          : Connection established
...
2021-10-09 01:36:00.158  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-2]  o.s.i.s.s.DefaultSftpSessionFactory      : The authenticity of host 'my.sftp.server.de' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 4d:fe:f9:35:08:20:2e:76:76:55:7a:1d:5d:5d:1c:90.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting?
2021-10-09 01:36:00.158  WARN [] --- [pool-240-thread-2]  com.jcraft.jsch                          : Permanently added 'my.sftp.server.de' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
...
2021-10-09 01:36:00.385  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-2]  com.jcraft.jsch                          : Authentication succeeded (publickey).
2021-10-09 01:36:00.447 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-2]  c.l.c.c.c.sftpConfiguration              : handleMessage message=GenericMessage [payload=[Lcom.harry.potter.job.miscellaneous.Event;@24b4484b, headers={file_remoteHostPort=my.sftp.server.de:22, file_name=EventData.txt, file_remoteDirectory=/data, file_originalFile=/home/app/sftp-inbound-work/EventData.txt, id=fa7b1773-d522-9f0f-e8ed-8fcf3bebe23a, file_relativePath=EventData.txt, file_remoteFile=EventData.txt, timestamp=1633736160447}]
2021-10-09 01:36:00.447 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-2]  c.l.c.c.c.sftpConfiguration              : deleteLocalFileService file=/home/app/sftp-inbound-work/EventData.txt removed
2021-10-09 01:36:00.447 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-2]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : postSend channel=bean 'sftpInputChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/harry/potter/job/config/sftpConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@1de2b65c', sent=true
2021-10-09 01:36:00.448 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : createEvents
2021-10-09 01:36:01.384  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  job-MyJob                                : Okay, send okay mail
2021-10-09 01:36:01.384 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : sendOkayMail
2021-10-09 01:36:01.512  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : MyJob finished
2021-10-09 01:36:01.512  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  job-MyJob                                : Job finished
2021-10-09 01:36:30.001  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : runAsTask: Storing Event Data, frequency=0/30 * * * * *
2021-10-09 01:36:30.001  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  job-MyJob                                : ---------------------------------------------------------------
2021-10-09 01:36:30.001  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  job-MyJob                                : Job started: Storing Event Data
2021-10-09 01:36:30.001 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : getFile
2021-10-09 01:36:30.002 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : getFile 'Start' control message sent successfully=true
2021-10-09 01:36:30.002 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : getFile, waiting for the file to be received, timeout=60s
2021-10-09 01:36:30.062 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-3]  c.l.c.c.c.sftpConfiguration              : handleMessage message=GenericMessage [payload=[Lcom.harry.potter.job.miscellaneous.Event;@b2cd829f, headers={file_remoteHostPort=my.sftp.server.de:22, file_name=EventData.txt, file_remoteDirectory=/data, file_originalFile=/home/app/sftp-inbound-work/EventData.txt, id=e6558e48-db84-fd2f-2195-c43d3e245127, file_relativePath=EventData.txt, file_remoteFile=EventData.txt, timestamp=1633736190062}]
2021-10-09 01:36:30.062 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-3]  c.l.c.c.c.sftpConfiguration              : deleteLocalFileService file=/home/app/sftp-inbound-work/EventData.txt removed
2021-10-09 01:36:30.062 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-3]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : postSend channel=bean 'sftpInputChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/harry/potter/job/config/sftpConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@1de2b65c', sent=true
2021-10-09 01:36:30.062 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-3]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : postSend channel=bean 'sftpInputChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/harry/potter/job/config/sftpConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@1de2b65c', sent=true
2021-10-09 01:36:30.062 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : createEvents
2021-10-09 01:36:30.394  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  job-MyJob                                : Okay, send okay mail
2021-10-09 01:36:30.395 DEBUG [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : sendOkayMail
2021-10-09 01:36:30.457  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  c.l.c.job.MyJobTask                      : MyJob finished
2021-10-09 01:36:30.457  INFO [] --- [pool-240-thread-1]  job-MyJob                                : Job finished
...
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : stopped bean 'sftpInboundAdapter'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/harry/potter/job/config/sftpConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method sftpInboundFlow'
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {json-to-object-transformer} as a subscriber to the 'sftpInboundFlow.channel#0' channel
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application-1.sftpInboundFlow.channel#0' has 0 subscriber(s).
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean 'sftpInboundFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/harry/potter/job/config/sftpConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method sftpInboundFlow'
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application-1.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {message-handler:sftpConfiguration.handler.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'sftpInputChannel' channel
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application-1.sftpInputChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean 'sftpConfiguration.handler.serviceActivator'
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {message-handler:sftpConfiguration.deleteLocalFileService.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'sftpInputChannel' channel
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application-1.sftpInputChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean 'sftpConfiguration.deleteLocalFileService.serviceActivator'
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {service-activator:sftpConfiguration.controlBus.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'controlChannel' channel
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application-1.controlChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean 'sftpConfiguration.controlBus.serviceActivator'
2021-10-09 01:38:43.697  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-2]  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you need a count down latch, you need a new interceptor each time (or use an `AtomicReference` with a new latch each time). You can call `removeInterceptor`.
2. There is also a remote filter.

However, for scenarios like this, it's much easier to use an outbound gateway with a GET command rather than using the async inbound channel adapter.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway

**EDIT**

Example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class So69511643Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69511643Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf(@Value("${host}") String host, @Value("${username}") String user,
            @Value("${pw}") String pw) {

        DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost(host);
        sf.setUser(user);
        sf.setPassword(pw);
        sf.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return sf;
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow(DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Gate.class)
                .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sf, Command.GET, "payload")
                        .localDirectoryExpression("'/tmp'"))
                .transform(new FileToStringTransformer())
                .transform(Transformers.fromJson(Foo.class))
                .get();
    }

}

interface Gate {

    Foo getFoo(String filename);

}

@Component
@DependsOn("flow")
class Scheduler {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So69511643Application.class);

    @Autowired
    Gate gate;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
    public void sched() {
        log.info("Fetched: {}", this.gate.getFoo("foo/bar.json"));
        new File("/tmp/bar.json").delete();
    }

}
```

**EDIT2**

Example using `.route` for fetch and delete:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class So69511643Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69511643Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf(@Value("${host}") String host, @Value("${username}") String user,
            @Value("${pw}") String pw, @Value("${pk}") Resource pk) {

        DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost(host);
        sf.setUser(user);
//      sf.setPassword(pw);
        sf.setPrivateKey(pk);
        sf.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return sf;
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow(DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf) {
        return f -> f
                .log()
                .route(Message.class, m -> m.getHeaders().get("method", String.class), r -> r
                        .subFlowMapping("getFoo", f1 -> f1
                            .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sf, Command.GET, "payload")
                                    .localDirectoryExpression("'/tmp'"))
                            .transform(new FileToStringTransformer())
                            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(Foo.class)))
                        .subFlowMapping("remove", f2 -> f2
                                .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sf, Command.RM, "payload"))));
    }

}

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "flow.input",
        defaultHeaders = @GatewayHeader(name = "method", expression = "#gatewayMethod.name"))
interface Gate {

    Foo getFoo(String filename);

    boolean remove(String filename);

}

@Component
@DependsOn("flow")
class Scheduler {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So69511643Application.class);

    @Autowired
    Gate gate;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
    public void sched() {
        log.info("Fetched: {}", this.gate.getFoo("foo/bar.json"));
        new File("/tmp/bar.json").delete();
        log.info("Deleted {}", this.gate.remove("foo/bar.json"));
    }

}
```

**EDIT3**

The above example defines the gateway proxy using an annotation only - you can't mix configuration between annotations and DSL. The following shows the same thing with the configuration of the gateway proxy using only the DSL.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class So69511643Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69511643Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf(@Value("${host}") String host, @Value("${username}") String user,
            @Value("${pw}") String pw, @Value("${pk}") Resource pk) {

        DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost(host);
        sf.setUser(user);
//      sf.setPassword(pw);
        sf.setPrivateKey(pk);
        sf.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return sf;
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow(DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Gate.class, g -> g
                        .header("method", args -> args.getMethod().getName()))
                .log()
                .route(Message.class, m -> m.getHeaders().get("method", String.class), r -> r
                        .subFlowMapping("getFoo", f1 -> f1
                            .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sf, Command.GET, "payload")
                                    .localDirectoryExpression("'/tmp'"))
                            .transform(new FileToStringTransformer())
                            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(Foo.class)))
                        .subFlowMapping("remove", f2 -> f2
                                .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sf, Command.RM, "payload"))))
                .get();
    }

}

interface Gate {

    Foo getFoo(String filename);

    boolean remove(String filename);

}

@Component
@DependsOn("flow")
class Scheduler {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So69511643Application.class);

    @Autowired
    Gate gate;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
    public void sched() {
        log.info("Fetched: {}", this.gate.getFoo("foo/bar.json"));
        new File("/tmp/bar.json").delete();
        log.info("Deleted {}", this.gate.remove("foo/bar.json"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Gary! Please could you explain what is ment by „There is also a remote filter“? I thought the RemoteFilter allows to control which file to get in case there are servers files on the SFTP server which I do not care about?
Yes, I started to use the SftpRemoteFileTemplate, which is a template based on the SftpOutboundGateway? There I did/do not know how to set JSON-to-Object transformation, which is just a `.transform(…)` method with the SftpInboundChannelAdapter.

Comment: The default (remote) `filter` is an `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` (with an in-memory store) so it should refetch the same file, as long as the timestamp changes. You can use `.handle(myBean, "myFetchMethod").transform(...)`.

Comment: I always changed the timestamp (even by setting it before to put the file to the SFTP server) during my tests. The `com.jcraft.jsch` package was doing something only the first time (as I tried to show in my LOG above).

The `.handle(...).transform(..)` is when using a SftpOutboundGateway? Is there a way to have that transformer set when using the SftpRemoteFileTemplate?

Comment: I can't explain why the file was not refetched; but, as I said, the gateway (or using the template) is a better solution for this use case. The `.handle().transform()` suggestion was if you are using the remote file template in a fetch method; to use the gateway, use the DSL.

Comment: Gary, can you give me a code snippet or a link to an example? Where - on which object - do I have to use the .handle().transform()? The SftpRemoteFileTemplate does not accept such a method.

Comment: I meant your own bean/method that uses the remote file template. Since you are familiar with the DSL, why not just use the gateway there? I can provide an example tomorrow if you still need help.

Comment: An example would be highly welcome, Gary!

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: It's terrific, Gary! I don't understand: I implement the class `GateImpl` (which implements Gate) outside with @Component annotation? Or a Gate.class itself? But the 'Interface Gate {...}` staff remains there? Can you explain what happens when stating `.from(Gate.class)`. Then the Gate.class is a MessageSource? Which method of the `Gate` class will provide the message?

Comment: The framework creates an implementation of `Gate`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway The `@DependsOn` forces the flow to be created first so we can inject that implementation.

Comment: Okay! My processing of the `Foo` entitites goes in `sched()` between your two lines. To delete the remote file I will have another `IntegrationFlow` with `Command.Rm`? And to have the backupped file I use FileUtils. Would you agree?

Comment: Yes; that sounds correct. You could simply use `Files.move()` to archive the retrieved file. That will be more efficient than copying the contents (as long as the source and destination are on the same disk).

Comment: If I had another `IntegrationFlow` with `Command.Rm` and/or `Command.Put`, is https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/gateway.html#messaging-gateway-annotation the way I could manage multiple outbound adapters with the same `gate.class` interface? Would you please add one other to your example?

Comment: You would either need a separate interface for each or add a .route() before the gateways based on the method name header. I am off work until Monday.

Comment: Hope you had some lovely days off, Gary! I am really looking forward getting your example with the `.rout()` specs at the two gatways and how the making of headers `method_name` is done!

Comment: It's probably simpler to use 2 ggateway interfaces, but I added an example anyway. See EDIT2.

Comment: No, no, it's very nice! Thanks! You changed the flow() method from `return IntegrationFlows.from(Gate.class)...` to a Lambda expression. Can you explain shortly why this change and which method represents the Lambda?
I see that f stands for flow, f1, f2 for subFlow. Mentioning the Gate.class is obsolete because we changed from saying to the flow "from where the message will come" to saying the gateway "to where the message will go"? We changed from MessageSource `Gate.class` to MessageHeader `getFoo/remove` multiplexing into two subFlows?

Comment: I added `@MessagingGateway(defaultHeaders = @GatewayHeader(name = "method", expression = "#gatewayMethod.name"))` to the interface to set the header; but I then realized you can't mix gateway proxy configuration between DSL and annotations; so I defined the gateway just using the annotation (and changed the flow definition to suit). The effect is the same. However, I will add another edit using purely the DSL (and remove the annotation). Yes, the router is like an if statement; if the header contains one value invoke one subflow, or the other value invoke the other.

Comment: You say "you can't mix DSL and annotations"? What will be the consequence? Your EDIT 2 runs without a problem. Should I change to your EDIT 3 anyway?

Comment: It's entirely your preference - all DSL or mixture of DSL and annotations - whichever you feel is easier to understand (for you and others) - when I had `from(Gate.class) ` and only `defaultHeaders` in the annotation, the proxy could not determine the name of the input channel - hence my final EDIT2 version to tell it the channel name in the annotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gary! The turning point for me was convincing me changing from the asynchronous `SftpInboundChannelAdapter` to the synchronous `SftpOutboundGateway`.